# copy data from one sheet to another sheet and update existing columns in destination sheet

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

I have 2 sheets, sheet1 has 2 columns:

```
A               B
employee Id     employee name
```

Sheet2 has 3 columns:

```
A               B                C
employee Id     employee name    Gender
```

I want to update my sheet2 when sheet1 changes and also if employee in sheet1 is added/deleted corresponding change should happen in sheet2 along with gender column.

Comment: Copying and pasting as link will help you in this in addition to the vlookup function if you are familiar with it.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could link each cell from Sheet1 to the corresponding field in Sheet2.
The syntax is as follows:

```
='SheetName'!CellReference
```

---

For example, to mimic Sheet1's A2 cell into a cell on a different sheet, this would be your formula:

```
='Sheet1'!A2
```

And if you want to link the whole columns, paste the links in the top-leftmost cell on Sheet2.